# Implicit Euler's Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems, fixed-point-iteration

Show that two solutions $x_n$ and $y_n$ generated by implicit Euler satisfy the inequality $|x_n - y_n|$ $\leq$ $|x_0 - y_0|$.

---

Can someone push me in the right direction by explaining to me how exactly implicit Euler's method works? I understand that it is some iteration method where $$u_{k+1} = u_k + hf(t_{k+1}, u_{k+1}).$$ And the $u_{k+1}$ is often found by some other iteration method (kind of shaky on this part here). I was wondering if there were some way to manipulate the equation to rewrite $x_n = x_{n+1} - hf(t_{k+1}, x_{k+1})$ and $y_n$ similarly but I'm not sure if that would get anything done. We are also given that $f$ satisfies the condition where $(x-y)(f(t,x)-f(t,y)) \leq 0$, which means $|x(t)-y(t)| \leq |x(0)-y(0)|$. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you just write down the difference of the two iterations and multiply with the right difference of arguments, you find that
\begin{align}
(x_+-y_+)^2&=(x_+-y_+)(x-y)+h(x_+-y_+)(f(t_+,x_+)-f(t_+,y_+))
\\
&\le (x_+-y_+)(x-y)
\end{align}
Now dividing by $|x_+-y_+|$ gives the desired result in one step and thus also in the general case.

---

Using Cauchy-Schwarz, this can also be extended to vector-valued ODE.

Comment: I think I'm following, but how do I get the $(x - y)$ to $|x - y|$ just by dividing $|x_{+} - y_{+}|$?

Comment: For any number you get $a\le|a|$. And obviously, the right side is non-negative, i.e., $0<ab$ implies $ab=|a|·|b|$.